# Inno setup WordWrap and Autosize

Tags: inno-setup

I'm creating a setup using Inno Setup, and I changed license page to not show license, but to link to it instead. I also added a `StaticText` to show some text, and the problem is that when I add too much text, I need `WordWrap := true`, and `AutoSize := false`, and this makes `StaticText` width in Setup created really small. Why it is sized if `AutoSize = false`? What to do to prevent it from minimizing when `WordWrap = true`. Change parent?

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
var  
 FormButton: TNewButton;
 Page: TWizardPage;
 ComboBox: TNewComboBox;
begin
  WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Hide;
  WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Hide;
  LicenseContextText := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm.InnerPage);
  with LicenseContextText do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.InnerPage;
    //TODO: check if we need 
    Left   := ScaleX(250);
    Top    := ScaleY(50);
    Height := ScaleY(100);
    Width  := ScaleX(1000); //200;
    //Color := clBlack;
    Font.Color := clGray;
    //WordWrap := true;
    //AutoSize := false;
    Caption := 'Some content text, Some content text, Some content text';// 
    Visible := false;
  end;
  LicenseLinkLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm.InnerPage);
  with LicenseLinkLabel do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.InnerPage;
    //TODO: check if we need 
    Left := 340;
    Top := 240;
    Height := 100;
    Cursor := crHand;
    Font.Color := clBlue;
    Font.Style := [fsUnderline];
    Caption := 'the License Agreement';
    OnClick := @LicenseLinkLabelClick;
    Visible := false;
  end;
  LicenseLinkURL := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm.InnerPage);
  with LicenseLinkURL do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm.InnerPage;
    Left := 277;
    Top := 238;
    Width := 60;
    Caption := ' I accept';
    OnClick := @OnLicenseCheckBoxClick;
    Visible := false;
  end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
 if (CurPageID = wpLicense) then
 begin
     WizardForm.Bevel1.Visible := false;
     WizardForm.MainPanel.Visible := false;
     WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Visible := false;
     LicenseLinkLabel.Visible := true;
     LicenseLinkURL.Visible := true;
     LicenseContextText.Visible := true;
```

Comment: .. so what's your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `AutoSize` and `WordWrap` properties before you set the `Width` and `Height` properties.

This is unrelated, but also rather than hard-coding specific values for the sizes you might want to consider using sizes relative to existing elements in the WizardForm, to eg. have it automatically fit to the width of the page area within the form.

Comment: Tnx a lot! I still think of scripts as of delphi compiler, my bad (